# Reduce Unity game iOS app size

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, size, filesize

In my editor log I have the info below. When I build to iOS and then archive and upload to testflight my build is 175MB. Is the 75 mb not including the .dlls? How can I find the size of these .dlls to try to eliminate the larger ones?

```
Textures      53.0 mb    70.4% 
Meshes        5.7 mb     7.6% 
Animations    249.3 kb   0.3% 
Sounds        10.1 mb    13.5% 
Shaders       60.9 kb    0.1% 
Other Assets  486.9 kb   0.6% 
Levels        750.7 kb   1.0% 
Scripts       613.1 kb   0.8% 
Included DLLs 4.1 mb     5.4% 
File headers  248.2 kb   0.3% 
Complete size 75.2 mb    100.0% 

Mono dependencies included in the build
Dependency assembly - Boo.Lang.dll
Dependency assembly - Mono.Security.dll
Dependency assembly - System.Core.dll
Dependency assembly - System.dll
Dependency assembly - mscorlib.dll
Dependency assembly - UnityEngine.Advertisements.dll
Dependency assembly - UnityEngine.UI.dll
Dependency assembly - UnityEngine.Networking.dll
Dependency assembly - UnityEngine.Analytics.dll
Dependency assembly - GETween.dll
Dependency assembly - Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll
Dependency assembly - Assembly-CSharp.dll
Dependency assembly - Assembly-UnityScript.dll
```

Comment: it could be that test flight doesnt do any sort of app thinning like the app store so the app will include a 32bit and 64bit binary, artificially inflating your app size

Comment: not sure if this will work, but maybe go to your build settings and under valid architectures, take out everything except arm64 and see if the app size is any different, if it does that will be an indication of how big your app will really be

Comment: Building to phone with just arm64 produces 114mb app on phone. archiving now and uploading to testflight

Comment: My 175MB build also does not have the warning next to it that the app will be over the 100MB limit, so this looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-3-x-build-size-increase-faq.383533/

The size of the app is due to the new system iOS is using. Basically, you have two apps in one (32-64bit) plus some extra info and some non-compressed data.

Once you upload to the AppStore, Apple will do the trimming and proper job and only then you will see the actual size of the app.